# MySQL LEFT JOIN not Working with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, left-join

I know there are lots of related questions around the web and,
the first answer would be GOOGLE it,
I don't need the First answer so thanks to every body the second one would be appreciated.

I have 4 Tables :

> Payment, InvoiceItem , User, Items

Relations :

> **Payment**.InvoiceItem_Id <-> **InvoiceItem**.InvoiceItemId
>
> **Payment**.User_Id <-> **User**.UserID
>
> **InvoiceItem**.Item_Id <-> **Items**.ItemsId

**Payment.InvoiceItem_Id** is NULLABLE so I have payments without InvoiceItems

and the Query is :

```
 
    SELECT 
        Payment.Id,
        Payment.User_Id,
        Payment.InvoiceItem_Id,
        User.Name,
        Items.Name
    FROM
        Payment
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
        InvoiceItem ON Payment.InvoiceItem_Id = InvoiceItem.InvoiceItemId
            INNER JOIN
        User ON Payment.User_Id = User.UserID
            INNER JOIN
        Items ON InvoiceItem.Items_Id = Items.ItemsId
    WHERE Payment.User_Id = 724;
```

If Ichange the third INNER JOIN to LEFT OUTER I will have all records from Payment but I dont know why I should change it cause third INNER JOIN is between **InvoiceItem**.Item_Id <-> **Items**.ItemsId and the query is supposed to be INNER JOIN on these to tables.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because once you have left outer joined to Invoice, performing an Inner Join on Invoice Items requires that ALL Invoice Items exist, effectively defeating your left join on Invoice.